# How to pass an unquoted column name to a custom summary function (min) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, custom-function

TLDR -Why doesn't this custom function work?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(date = c("2023-06-01", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-03"),
                  shots = c(8, 12, 10),
                  passes = c(340, 410, 390))

cust_ggplot <- function(df, date, metric){
  
  min_date <- min({{ date }}) # invalid 'type' (closure argument)
  # min_date <- min(!! ensym(date))  # Error in !ensym(x): invalid argument type.
  # min_date <- min(df[[date]]) # works if date is enclosed in quotes like this dat |> cust_title("date", "shots")
                                # But I want it to look like tidyverse function with no quotes needed.
  
}

dat |> 
  cust_ggplot(date, shots)
```

### I would like to emulate the tidyverse style and not have to use `dat |> cust_title("date", "shots")`

Full walkthru:
I am trying to turn this simple ggplot code into a function.

```
### Data
dat <- data.frame(date = c("2023-06-01", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-03"),
                  shots = c(8, 12, 10),
                  passes = c(340, 410, 390)
)

### Working Code
dat |>
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = shots)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle(
    paste(
      "Shot Totals from",
      min(dat$date),
      "-",
      max(dat$date)
    )
  )
```

I can get the plot to work just fine via

```
### Turn it into a function

# This portion works
cust_ggplot <- function(df, date, metric){
  
  df |>
    ggplot(aes(x = {{ date }}, y = {{ metric }} )) +
    geom_col() 
  
}

dat |> 
  cust_ggplot(date, shots) +
  ggtitle("Shot Totals")
```

But when I try to find the min or max dates to pass to the subtitle, none of my attempts work.

```
cust_ggplot <- function(df, date, metric){
  
  # min_date <- min({{ date }}) invalid 'type' (closure argument)
  # min_date <- min(!! ensym(date))  #Error in !ensym(x): invalid argument type.
  # min_date <- min(df[[date]]) # works if date is enclosed in quotes like this dat |> cust_title("date", "shots")
                                # But I want it to look like tidyverse function with no quotes needed.
  
  df |>
    ggplot(aes(x = {{ date }}, y = {{ metric }} )) +
    geom_col() 
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are likely quite a few ways to accomplish this, but one thing you could do is this:

```
min_date <- df |> pull({{date}}) |> min()
```

(Minor point: I find it a little confusing to read the function when you name the arguments using the same name as the values you're likely to pass in. If it were me I'd use more generic argument names like `function(df, var1, var2)` or something.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as_label` former `quo_name` from `rlang` package: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quo_label.html

#### These functions take an arbitrary R object, typically an expression, and represent it as a string.

##### Using this example data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  date = c("2023-06-01", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-03"),
  shots = c(8, 12, 10),
  passes = c(340, 410, 390)
)
```

##### you want to bring this working ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = shots))+
  geom_col()+
  ggtitle(paste("Shot Totals from", min(dat$date), "-", max(dat$date))
          )
```

##### to a custom function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

cust_ggplot <- function(df, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)  # Quote the 'x' argument
  y <- enquo(y)  # Quote the 'y' argument
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x = !!x, y = !!y)) +
    geom_col() +
    ggtitle(paste("Shot Totals from", min(df[[as_label(x)]]), "-", max(df[[as_label(x)]])))
}

cust_ggplot(dat, date, shots)
```

[image]